# Unable to pass dynamic data from controller to view when using $data['firstname'] = $this->firstname

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I am very new to CodeIgniter. I have been facing a very irritating problem for many hours.
This is the code

```
    <?php
    class Hello extends CI_Controller
    {
     var $firstname;
 var $lastname;

    function _construct()
{
  parent::_construct();
  $this->firstname='Ashutosh';
  $this->lastname='Bajpay';

}

function you()
{ 
  $data['firstname'] = $this->firstname;
  $data['lastname'] = $this->lastname;
  $this->load->view('ashu',$data);
}
   }
   ?>
```

and the view file ashu.php is-

```
     Hello, <?php echo $firstname;?> <?php echo $lastname;?>! This is your second     CodeIgniter program.
```

and the output is-

> Hello, !This is your second CodeIgniter program.

but when I am writng-

```
    function you()
{ 
  $data['firstname'] = 'Ashutosh';
  $data['lastname'] = 'Bajpay';
  $this->load->view('ashu',$data);
}
```

then output is as wanted-

> Hello, Ashutosh Bajpay!This is your second CodeIgniter program.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
     var $firstname;
     var $lastname;
```

to

```
    private  $firstname;
    private  $lastname;
```

Comment: what do you get when you print $this->firstname and $this->lastname in your function you() .

Comment: here it is. As __construct has two underscore as prefix and i have used one.